# I can't find this article

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, specific-reference

Does anyone know the DOI of the article below or where I can download it?

P. Rhodes and G. Rowlands, “Demagnetising energies of uniformly
magnetized rectangular blocks,” Proc. Leeds Phil. Lit. Soc., vol. 6, pp.
191–210, Dec. 1954.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library

Comment: 1. Are you sure there is a "the DOI of the article"? 2. Consider [How can I find an old, obscure, or otherwise inaccessible paper when the usual methods fail?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/134634/17254) on Academia.SE

Comment: try https://www.academia.edu/7326516/Demagnetizing_factors_for_square_bars

Comment: @annav Not sure what I'm missing, but that link seems to point to an entirely different paper, with a similar but different title, by different authors, and published 50 years later in a different venue?